Parsing a hex value with spaces, last two characters are dropped
I have a script that gets snmpv3 engineID's from devices.
It's been working fine on both my dev servers and my uat server. I moved the code from one to the next by creating a tar file of all my snmp configuration files, including the script and extracted the tar to the next server and recycled the services. On each one the snmpv3 traps get written to the log file.
Yesterday I moved it to production and no traps are logging.
in diagnosing that, I noticed that my snmpget command is dropping the last two digits of the hex string.
My code:
if test $snmpget_RC -eq 0
    then
        read dc1 dc2 dc3 hex < <(snmpget -v3 -l authPriv -u $UserName -a SHA -A mypassword -x AES -X myauthphrase $myIP SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0)
        MyHex=`echo $hex |sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g'`
        echo 'createUser -e' $MyHex  $UserName' SHA mypassword AES myauthphrase' >>$snmpPath/$MyFile
    else
        echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') $myIP is not reachable" >> $myLog
        RC=0
fi

Running snmpget from the CLI returns
SNMP-FRAMEWORK-MIB::snmpEngineID.0 = Hex-STRING: 80 00 92 C4 04 53 4E 2D 35 33 32 30 34 35 37 32

39

I modified the script to echo the hex when running it interactively.
Hex value for deviceFQDN is 00092C404534E2D3533323034353732

As you can see, the read command isn't seeing the 39. (which makes me wonder why traps are logged on the other 3 servers, but that's another rabbit hole).
How can I fix the read command so the entire hex is captured?

The first echo command does not make sense. Single quotes inhibit parameter expansion. Therefore your MyHex variable won't be expanded.

It can be pretty bad an idea to parse console app output, as the output format can go beyond your control and imagination. But if you learn a little bit Python and perform SNMP operations from there, you have full access to the actual objects/values and also have full control on how to output them to meet your requirements.

user1934428 That could very well be, but that's how it was provided in another thread and seems to be working. Except for the two dropped characters which is apparently the result of using read

Lex Li, Thanks, and yes, I need to learn python. I needed something quick and dirty to meet a requirement, but plan to redo it in Python for more automation (reading devices from SQL).

Your snmpget outputs two lines with the 39 on the second line, but shell read reads ONE line. I notice most of the value can be interpreted as ASCII 'SN-532045729' which looks like a serial number; if so, perhaps the 3 working servers have serial numbers at least one digit shorter so they fit on the first line.
In bash or zsh you can use read -d '' ... to read both (or in general multiple) lines, and the subsequent echo $hex (unquoted!) will effectively convert the newline to a space (specifically, expanding unquoted $hex breaks into separate arguments at any IFS character which by default includes space tab or newline, then echo joins its arguments back together with space). Although in bash or zsh you don't need the echo-plus-sed at all, just use ${hex//[[:space:]]}
dash gives an error for -d and ksh93 accepts it but seems to ignore it (at least in my Ubuntu). For a POSIX shell if your script doesn't need the positional arguments at this point you could use them:
set -- $(snmpget ...) # breaks at IFS which by default includes space and newline
shift 3 # $*/$@ now contains only the hex fields
IFS=""; # then use "$*" (in quotes to prevent resplitting) in place of $myhex


It's close, but I guess I'm not understanding exactly what you meant.

Sorry, forgot you can't hit Enter for a new line in comments. anwyay --- It's close, but I guess I'm not understanding exactly what you meant. The set -- $(snmpget ...) gets the entire hex, but after trying the next part I'm still getting 80 00 92 C4 04 53 4E 2D 35 33 32 30 34 35 37 32 39. I tried echo "$*" and IFS="$*", echo $IFS

Rovernut: as I said, set IFS empty IFS=""; THEN use "$*" where you had $myhex e.g. echo 'createuser -e'"$*" blah blah

Even though I didn't fully understand Dave's answer, set -- $(snmpget...) works because, as it turns out, the spaces in the EngineID in snmptrapd.conf can be present and traps are received and logged.

Hah, you submitted while I was typing my comment above.
So I'll ask, what's the purpose of IFS=""? I didn't do that and it's working  fine, receiving traps from multiple devices.
Or is it just not working in my environment for removing the spaces?

Setting IFS="" then using "$*" combines the returned tokens (hex bytes) into a single string without spaces, as your Q apparently required. If in fact it's not required, then you don't need to do it.

It turns out I have to remove the spaces and only got it partially working.I couldn't figure out how to ask an extended follow-up so I asked a new question here: https://shorturl.at/x1Uuv
